# Input either from stdin or file , C

Tags: c, file, input, stdin

I have a program that either reads an input from a file or from the keyboard. I have found a way to decide whether the input should be inserted from a file or from keyboard.

I need to implement that decision with an easy way, as I don't want to copy my code 2 times for each type of input.

I tried something like the code bellow but worked only for an input file (arv == 1), while it gets a segmentation fault from stdin.

*error after debugging for arg == 0*

```
(_IO_fgets (buf=0xbffffaac "\030\031\023", n=100, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:52)
```

Code:

```
FILE *fp;

if (arg = 1)
    fp = fopen (operationfile, "r");
else
    fp = stdin;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL)
```

Is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: Always check the return values of your function calls when there is a possibility that they will fail.  I/O functions such as `fopen()` are particularly exposed to failure; it is rare for it not to be appropriate to check their return values.  In this case, you could have detected that you failed to open the file in the error case, instead of getting a mysterious segfault.

Comment: It is good that you're writing your code so that you use the same code for both standard input and a named file.  It is often appropriate to put the reading code into a function that is passed the file stream (and perhaps the file name in case it needs to generate an error message).  This allows you to generalize your code more easily.

Comment: the signature for main() when there are command line parameters is: `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   in C, the `argc` parameter will NEVER be less that 1.  because `argv[0]` is a pointer to a char string containing `path/name` for the program executable.  To have a single command line parameter, the value of `argc` will be 2 and the parameter will be available at `argv[1]` as a pointer to a char string.

Comment: this line: `if (arg = 1)` is a common keypunch error that the compiler will not catch.  However if the literal is on the left, as in `if ( 1 = arg)` then the compiler would have caught it and debugging would have been MUCH MUCH easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(arg == 1) /* == */
{
    ....
```

should take care of much of your trouble.  `arg = 1` sets `arg` to 1 and always succeeds, so the `fp=stdin;` branch is never used.

Also, your question doesn't show how `arg` is assigned.  Is it the first parameter of `main()`?  If so, that's usually called `argc`.  If you use the conventional name, other developers will have an easier time understanding your code.

**Edits**

- As @MayurK points out, using `1 == arg` rather than `arg == 1` will help the compiler protect you from this.
- As @EdHeal points out, some compilers have options to check for `if(arg=1)`, since it's rarely what you want.  In GCC, `-Wint-in-bool-context` and `-Wparentheses` are useful (or, better yet, just fire up `-Wall`!).

Comment: Perhaps mention that some compilers have an option to detect such a mistake

Comment: It is always a good practise to write constant at LHS, i.,e. if(1 == arg){}. Compiler will throw error if you write "=" instead of "==".

Comment: Well gcc did not detect it . You were right . Don't worry about the arg , they are main arguments. Problem solved thanks !

Comment: @MayurK: I regard Yoda-conditions as abominable.  I do not recommend them.  Most compilers can be provoked into warning about assignments in conditional contexts — if you aren't using such a compiler, it is time to upgrade; if you aren't routinely using that level of warning, you should be; and if you're ignoring compiler warnings, you shouldn't be.

Comment: @EugG: If GCC didn't give you the warning, you are effectively misusing GCC.  You get the warning if you use the `-Wall` flag, which is the bare minimum level.  When invoked with no warnings-enabled options, GCC accepts a lot of code that is dubious by modern standards — it was more of an issue before GCC 5.x and later defaulted to C11, because the C89 standard was both remarkably successful and remarkably lax (of necessity). I seldom post code on SO that won't compile with `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wold-style-definition`.